# fill String array Android

Tags: android, json

I have a problem with the filling of a String array. Should I fill it using data taken from a database?
The process of data extraction works, as evidenced by the LogCat, so I think the problem is right in the filling.
Here is the Java code snippet.

```
 for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

   result_string =  json_data.getString("nome")+" "+json_data.getString("cognome")+ 
         ":presente "+json_data.getString("dettagli");
    farmacisti[i] = jArray.getString(i);
 }
```

When I check in LogCat what is in the string `stringaFarmacisti`, I get this:

> [Ljava.lang.String; @ 4126d308

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: because that's what it is supposed to be. this is the string representation of an array ([) of java.lang.String that has an address or something that is 4126d308. What did you expect ?

Comment: Don't worry guys, i found the error .... it was very simple, i was careless ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to fill the array with result_string...

```
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        result_string =  json_data.getString("nome")+" "+json_data.getString("cognome")+ ": presente "+json_data.getString("dettagli");

        farmacisti[i] = result_string;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.out.println("farmacisti: " + Arrays.toString(farmacisti));
```

to see what's inside `farmacisti` array.